# Extending ZfcUser Authorization

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am looking for some kind of direction and/or guidance on how to best extend zfcuser to include a third property for authentication beyond username/email & password.

I am looking to add a "domain" field to include in authentication.

I have figured out how to use a custom entity to add the property to the user object (and orm mapping) and adding it to the login form, but I need authenticate to use the third field along with username/email & password and be available in the identity that is set.

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Comment: You will probably need to override the `ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db` auth adapter entirely to get this to work

Comment: So to make sure I understand correctly, to do that I would create a Authentication/Adapter/MyAuth and then in my custom auth controller, create my own loginAction to process the login and use my auth adapter?